# Which stationary varifolds have non-integer density?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

A central object in geometric measure theory are the generalised, and weakly defined minimal surfaces called *stationary varifolds*. Let me recall some definitions. Given an open subset $U \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+k}$,

- an $n$-dimensional *rectifiable varifold* is a pair $V = (M,\theta)$ consisting of an $n$-rectifiable subset $M \subset U$ and a function $\theta \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(M;[0,\infty))$, where the integrability is measured with respect to the restriction of the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^n$ to $M$;
- its *mass* is the Radon measure $\lVert V \rVert$ defined by $\langle \lVert V \rVert , \varphi \rangle = \int_{M \cap U} \varphi(x) \theta(x) \, \mathrm{d} \mathcal{H}^n(x)$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^1(U)$, and we may assume that $M = \mathrm{spt} \lVert V \rVert$;
- when the function $\theta$ (also called the *density function*) takes integer values, then the varifold $V$ is called *integral*;
- the varifold $V$ is called *stationary* if for the flow $(\Phi_t)$ of any  all compactly supported vector fields $X \in C_c^1(U;\mathbf{R}^{n+k})$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}(\Phi_t)_* \lVert V \rVert = 0$ at time $t = 0$, where $(\Phi_t)_*$ denotes the pushforward in the sense of measures.

Given a *bona fide* smooth embedded minimal surface $M \subset U$, one easily obtains stationary  varifolds by picking a constant density function, say $\theta \equiv \theta_0 > 0$. The corresponding varifold $V = (M,\theta)$ is not integral unless of course $\theta_0 \in \mathbf{Z}$. That being said, there *exists* an integer-valued density function that 'makes $M$ stationary', e.g. $(M,\theta \equiv 1)$.

A paper of [Kolar](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3677) implies that this is not always possible when $\theta$ is allowed to take arbitrarily small (positive) values. This motivates the following question.

**Question**. What examples are there of stationary rectifiable varifolds $V$ (defined in some open subset $U \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+k}$) for which there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $\theta \geq \delta$ $\mathcal{H}^n$-a.e. on $\mathrm{spt} \lVert V \rVert$, but for which there is *no* integer-valued function $\theta' \in L^1(\mathrm{spt} \lVert V \rVert;[0,\infty))$ say so that $(\mathrm{spt} \lVert V \rVert,\theta')$ is stationary?

This question can be rephrased in a slightly less stiff way as follows. Let $V$ be a stationary rectifiable varifold, whose density is bounded below, away from zero. Must there be *some* integer-valued function $\theta'$ so that weighting $\mathrm{spt} \lVert V \rVert$ by $\theta'$ produces a stationary varifold?

Comment: I think I just realised that there is a relatively trivial answer, by modifying a triple junction. Three half-lines meeting at a common point with angles $2\pi/3$ form a stationary varifold when they are weighted by the same density. Moreover this is the *only* way the three lines can be arranged when the varifold is integral, I believe. When they are given other densities, then the lines can meet at different angles and retain stationarity: their support can therefore not be made into a stationary *integral* varifold.

Comment: I think you already have the answer. But as an note, there is a beautiful related example by Young '63 (see also White '84, and Morgan '84 for extensions), for minimal oriented surfaces (i.e. currents) with a fixed integer density boundary: If you pick a nontrivial curve on a Klein bottle and give it density 1 and an orientation, then the only current with that boundary is 1/2 times the Klein bottle with orientation flipping when crossing the curve. If you embed the manifold in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then you can show that for some curves, this actually has less mass than any integer current.